# Bookmark Link to Heading Not Working

Tags: html

I have a table of contents at the top of a web page that points to bookmarks within the page.  This is what I've got:

```
<a href="#sect1">Section 1</a>
<a href="#sect2">Section 2</a>
<a href="#sect3">Section 3</a>

...

<h2 id="sect1">Section 1</h2>
<p>This is my first section</p>

<h2 id="sect2">Section 2</h2>
<p>This is my second section</p>

<h2 id="sect3">Section 3</h2>
<p>This is my third section</p>
```

The problem is that (when clicking on a TOC item) the page focus moves directly to that section's text such that the section's heading becomes hidden.  You then have to scroll up to uncover the section's heading.  In other words, the focus seems to be moving to AFTER the bookmark.  I want it to move to BEFORE the bookmark.

How do I fix this so that the heading remains visible?

Comment: You probably misplaced the "#",

<a href="#sect1">...
..
.. id="sect1"...

Comment: I just noticed that and corrected it in the question.  The # appears in the TOC entries and doesn't work in the way I described.

Comment: are you using position:absolute? bookmark links don't play well with them. we need more code to figure this out because the code you provided works just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if postion: absolute is coming into play here as I can't follow all the CSS in my style sheet.  I have found, however, that a "header" section in my page that appears before the "article" section is causing the problem.  I just have no idea why.

Comment: Code sample is at http://http://162.243.61.184/test.html and corresponding CSS style sheet is at http://162.243.61.184/css/style.css